# Unable to update Box2D?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, box2d-iphone

I'm using Cocos2D 1.0.1, and it doesn't get the latest Box2d. So, I would like to update it to the latest version (v2.2.1).
I've followed these steps (the steps are from [here](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/archives/1112)):

1. From within Xcode, delete the Box2D folder group from the “cocos2d
   Sources” folder (Delete References)
2. From Finder, go to your project’s folder and delete the Box2D folder
3. Copy over the latest version of Box2D back into your project’s
   folder (make sure you only copy the most deep rooted “Box2D” folder,
   and delete CMakeLists.txt and Box2DConfig.cmake)
4. Back to Xcode, Project -> Add to Project, select the Box2D folder,
   make sure create groups (not folder reference) is selected, Add

I did everything in these steps, but I get the many errors in GLES-Render and one error about initializing the `b2World` 
How can I fix these errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change the initialization of Box2D. The line where you do `new b2World(…)`. [It doesn't take the same parameters as before](http://learn-cocos2d.com/api-ref/latest/Box2D/html/classb2_world.html), just a gravity vector.

Then open GLES-Render.h and change the class it subclasses from to `b2Draw`. I believe it was previously named `b2DebugDraw`.

Now, learn the lesson that upgrading a source code package is practically never as easy as they say it is. More so the older the description of the upgrade process. That's why it's always good advice to make those changes in a copy of the project, and upgrade only if you really have to.